# How to split multiple audio inputs?

Tags: audio-recording, input

I want to split multiple sound inputs (electric guitars) into separate sound devices in Windows. I.e. guitar1 => audio_device1, guitar2 => audio_device2 and so on. To be able to control each device separately on the computer. What is the best device for me to use for this?

Comment: You already have 2; left and right. For about $100 you can have 4. More than that it basically goes straight to 12+ on any *multitrack* USB mixer worth buying. If you have a PC with an ISA slot, get a M-Audio Delta 1010LT (ten in, ten out, plus MIDI) which was $200 20y ago and still $200 because it does what it says on the tin and it's still the only offering at that price range that does that afaik.

Answer (score 3):

You want an audio interface - these come in many sizes, so buy one with the number of inputs you need - and this will allow you to control your inputs individually.

Most of these interfaces work well with any DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) which will give you more extensive control (effects, EQ, editing etc)

Comment: buy one with the number of [**outputs**] you need. "USB MTK" - lots of them have 12 *ins* with only the 2 out. That doesn't let you mess with it later in a computer. And those are $500.... Basically, the Soundcraft Signature 12. Which is getting hard to find. Or a junk CPU that still has slots in it and use an M Delta card. Also probably hard to find. - If all they want to do is mix live then any mixer will do.

Comment: @Mazura pretty easy to find ones with as many in or out as you want. It's all just a cost option.

Comment: I'm looking for more than four, for less than six hundred. Which only seems to exist as an ancient PC card that you still need a basic mixer in between. - Just kinda aggravating that it's still a budding tech 20y latter. If you don't reed the fine print they don't do what seems should be obvious to me.

Comment: The OP is only asking about inputs, though. Consumer prices are pretty good. Combine decent interface with Cubase or other reasonable DAW and you're grand. you can get 4, 8, 12, 16, 32 and then you get into more money than I have.

Comment: "How to split multiple audio inputs ...To be able to control each device *separately* on the computer." - That depends on the interface's number of *outputs*, which it will of course have more, or the same number of, *ins* than *outs*. - I think the OP is asking how to turn a computer into a *legit* DAW. - I took a look at these https://www.gearank.com/guides/audio-interface - IDK why you'd drop ~400 on something with knobs instead of actual faders like the Sig. 12 for 600. (*mobility* is not the name of my game ;)

Comment: To control each device separately on the computer, you only need USB. The various devices I use have multiple inputs, and yeah, multiple outputs, but I usually only use the 1 - USB into the PC, where each input is treated separately, and has a separate track in my DAW

Comment: Sig 12 : "USB Interface 14-in/ *12-out* " - Behringer Xenyx X1222USB Mixer with USB and Effects : "Best of all, you can easily record *the stereo output* of the X1222USB to your computer via USB". - Yours is a USB *MTK*.

Answer (score 0):

You want an audio interface... that has USB to PC, where each input is treated separately, and has a separate track in a DAW.

Which needs to say on it, *#X out via USB*, not *'stereo output'* nor where it mentions nothing about it which means it's probably just L/R.

The search term seems to be (USB) *MTK* (multitrack). But I'd still read the fine print about its number of channels that it can send across the USB individually.

---

https://www.gearank.com/guides/audio-interface

> Things to Consider When Buying an Audio Interface

> Number of Inputs vs Channel Count

> This is the **number of analog inputs that can be transferred to separate tracks on your computer**, which sounds simple. However, some manufacturers fudge the number slightly to give a higher channel count.

> Many of them include digital input channels to their devices, such as SP/DIF or ADAT in the channel count, even though these would require another piece of hardware acting as an audio interface (EG, some mixers and mic preamps also provide A/D conversion) to allow them to be used. So, a "16 channel audio interface" might only handle 8 analog inputs.

> Therefore, **we've classified the interfaces in our guide by the number of analog channels that can be input and sent as separate channels via USB**. Not that these extra digital input channels are a handy option when you want to expand, but they won't help you if you don't have another compatible audio interface. A rack mount audio interface might not always come with 8 XLR inputs.

> Note that some compact USB audio interfaces, like the Behringer UCA222, have no XLR inputs. They are meant for a different purpose, like connecting a mixer to a computer via RCA inputs.